# read and update a txt file in Scilab

Tags: save, load, readfile, scilab

I want to read and update my '.txt' file with the name 'Stock' and contain the following data:

Nom Nombre  Code

Pull    25  Ni

Pantalon  12    L

Foulard   33    N

How I can remove one article or add a new one in the same file and then save it?

I succeeded in opening the file and reading the data in the form of structure, then I added a new item. I want to know how to save this new data in the 'stock.txt' file.

Comment: Please include your actual code in the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.